# Sending a username/password to URL and returning an ID number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, mobile

I have to send some login credentials to our server, which will validate them and send a customer ID back. Actually it displays the customer ID on the screen if you visit the URL from a browser. I have written the part the fabricates the URL, but I don;t know how to make such a request and then return that Customer ID into a string in my iphone app.

An example URL to a test account is: https://order.americantaxi.com/ATOnlineOrderWeb/servlet/SmartApp?command=login&u=babarshabbir&p=babarshabbir

Any pointer in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/) in the iOS developer library.

Comment: I've looked at that, but I'm still not sure how to return the string, It looks like I want to use NSURLRequest but how do I get a string from that?